# can i create a common code with HTML, CSS and Javascript that works in iPhone , Android and Blackberry OS under Phonegap build

Tags: android, iphone, html, blackberry

Can i create a common web app using HTML, CSS and Javascript for iPhone 4.3 and later, Android 2.2 and later and Blackberry OS6 using phone gap framework

1. If yes whether it is going to be complex when compared to creating individual web app for each platform? Since the common web app has to take care of UI features of all the platforms...
2. What is best way to achieve this in the code using CSS?

Please let me know possible solution and any examples based on this requirement.

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

**About PhoneGap**

PhoneGap *(also called Apache Callback)* is an **open-source mobile development framework developed by Nitobi Software**. It enables software programmers to build applications for mobile devices using *JavaScript, HTML5 and CSS3, instead of often less-known languages such as Objective-C*. The resulting applications are **hybrid:-** meaning that they are *neither truly native (all layout rendering is done via the webview instead of Objective-C or Corona apps) nor purely web based (much of the functions would be supported by HTML5)*. One **disadvantage is that hybrid applications do not have full access to the device application programming interface (API)**.

**SUPPORTED PLATFORM**

PhoneGap currently supports development for the operating systems `Apple iOS, Google Android, HP webOS, Microsoft Windows Mobile, Nokia Symbian OS and RIM BlackBerry`. Support for recent versions, such as BlackBerry 5 and 6 and Windows Phone 7, is being implemented now. `Bada (the operating system used by the Samsung Wave S8500) support is "coming soon"`.

**SUPPORTED FEATURES**

- Accelerometer
- Camera
- Compass
- Contacts
- File
- GeolocationMedia
- Network Notification
- (Alert) Notification
- (Sound) Notification
- (Vibration) Storage

In **iPhone** only **Compass** is not available in 3g but in newer version this is also supported

In **Android** all features are available

In **windows Phone 7** all features are available

In **RIM BLACKBERRY 5.x- 6.0** compass and media not available in **BLACKBERRY4.6-4.7** Accelerometer, camera , compass, contacts, File, geolocation and Storage not available

HERE are the link for some of the Os you are targetting

**BLACKBERRY** [Getting started with PhoneGap for BlackBerry](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494777/Getting%20Started%20with%20PhoneGap%20%28BlackBerry%29)

**iPhone** [Getting started with PhoneGap for iPhone](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494778/Getting%20Started%20with%20PhoneGap%20%28iOS%29%20-%20Xcode%203)

**Android** [Getting started with PhoneGap for Android](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/getting-started-phonegap)

Comment: Thanks BBdev but my intention was to know whether creating a common Web Folder(HTML,CSS, JS) for all platforms is going to be complex in terms of UI screen alignments and responses?

Comment: no that will not happen if you don't hard code the values and its easy some small modification will do this isn't it